# Filling empty cells of a matrix with random values in java

Tags: java, matrix, random, fill, unique-values

I am trying to make a matrix in `Java` that is going to be filled with random values only in that positions that are empty. I am trying these code but it doesn't work.
I made two nested `for` loops, one for the rows and one for the columns. And for every position, I ask if it's `0` (I'm not sure how to make a control on that) and if it does not generate a random coordinate and print it in the format (i,j). *But it is always printing `0`*.

```
public int[][] getRandomPosition(int matrixlength) {
       int[][] grid = new int[matrixlength][matrixlength];

       for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
             if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
                grid[i][j] = (int) Math.random();
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
                return grid;
             }
          }
       }
       return null;
}
```

Any idea of how I can resolve the problem at hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason as to why it's always printing zero is because of `Math.random()` returns a number from `0.0` to `0.9` inclusive therefore once you cast the result returned from `Math.random()` to an `int`, *it will always result in `0`*.

Solution to your problem; you could either use the `Random` class and utilize its [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) method or use the formula below:

```
grid[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); // where min is the minimum value you want to generate and max is the max you want to generate (exclusive).
```

Though I'd recommend the former, and you'd first need to create a `Random` object prior to the outer loop i.e

```
Random randomGen = new Random();
```

then within your, `if` block, you can do:

```
grid[i][j] = randomGen.nextInt();
```

There's also another [`Random#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) overload which enables you to specify the bounds of the random numbers being generated.

Answer (score 0):

[`Math.radnom()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) returns a `double` that's greater or equal than `0.0` and less than `1.0`. When you cast it to an `int`, it will be truncated to `0`. Instead, you need to generate a random `int`. Additionally, you shouldn't return the grid before filling it up completely. E.g.:

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
        if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
            grid[i][j] = rand.nextInt();
        }
     }
}
```